# Статический стек Delphi

Tags: delphi, стек, pascal

**почему при вызове  Push() ничего не происходит?**

```
type
  TStack = record
  StackArray : array [1..5] of Integer;
  top : Integer;
end;

var MyStack : TStack;
  i,a,x : Integer;
procedure Push(s : TStack;a : Integer);
begin
  s.top := s.top + 1;
  s.StackArray[s.top] := a;
end;
procedure Pop(s : TStack);
begin
  s.top := s.top - 1;
end;

function TTop(s : TStack) : Integer;
  begin
    TTop := s.StackArray[s.top];
  end;

begin
  MyStack.top := 0;

  Push(MyStack,23);
  Write('TOP : ');
  writeln(MyStack.top);

  Readln;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

В Delphi record-ы передаются по значению, а не по ссылке. Т.е. внутри процедуры создается локальная копия, и поэтому изменение параметра `s` внутри процедуры `Push` никак не скажется на состоянии `MyStack`.

Чтобы добиться желаемого, добавьте `var` к параметру `s`:

```
procedure Push(var s : TStack;a : Integer);
begin
  s.top := s.top + 1;
  s.StackArray[s.top] := a;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Если сильно хотите модуль работы со стеками:

```
unit UStack;

interface

type PStack=^_Stack;

     _Stack=record
         X,Y,Scale:Extended;
         next:PStack;
     end;
     TStack=object
         private
             Top:PStack;
         public
             Constructor create;
             destructor done;
             Procedure Clear;
             Procedure Push(XX,YY,_Scale:extended);
             Function Pop(var XX,YY,_Scale:extended):boolean;
     end;
implementation

{ TStack }

procedure TStack.Clear;

 Var a:PStack;

begin

    while Top<>nil do
    begin
        a:=top;
        top:=a^.next;
        dispose(a);
    end;
end;

constructor TStack.create;

begin

    top:=nil;
end;

destructor TStack.done;

begin

    clear;
end;

function TStack.Pop(var XX, YY, _Scale: extended): boolean;

var a:PStack;

begin

    if top<>nil then
    begin
      pop:=true;
      a:=top;
      top:=a^.next;
      xx:=a^.X;
      yy:=a^.Y;
      _Scale:=a^.Scale;
      dispose(a);
    end else pop:=false;
end;

procedure TStack.Push(XX, YY, _Scale: extended);

var a:PStack;

begin

    new(a);
    a^.X:=xx;
    a^.Y:=yy;
    a^.Scale:=_Scale;
    a^.next:=top;
    top:=a;
end;

end.
```

Естественно регистрируете у себя в программе обект типа `TStack`

Будьте внимательны. Объекты статичны, и любой из методов может быть использован в программе до конструкции. Метод вызова конструктора слегка отличается от класса.

Вы пишите в основной программе:

.

```
..

Var ST : TStack;

....

Begin

  ST.Create;

...

...

  ST.Done;

end;
```

Ну или как иначе. Но прога писалась еще на турбике, и я лично заломался переводить  классы.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужен нормальный стек, а не собственный велосипед, то лучше воспользуйтесь дженериковой коллекцией [TStack](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/Generics_Collections_TStack_%28Delphi%29) (XE4+).